# Top down shooter. How could I make the bullets fire in the direction the player is aiming?

Tags: java, rotation, drawing

I have a player made out of rectangles. I currently have it so that it always aims towards the mouse. I would like the player to be able to fire the bullets straight towards the mouse but I am unsure of what equation I would use to make the bullet move the correct amount along the x and y so that it meets the point it is aimed at.

This is what I currently have for the player.

```
public void playerImage(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    theta = Math.atan2(playerY - InputHandler.mouseY + playerHeight / 2,
            playerX - InputHandler.mouseX + playerWidth / 2) - Math.PI / 2;
    g2d.rotate(theta, playerX + playerWidth / 2, playerY + playerHeight / 2);
    g2d.setColor(Color.blue.darker());
    // Main body
    g2d.drawRect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
    // Left arm
    g2d.drawRect(playerX - playerWidth / 2, playerY, playerWidth / 2,
            playerHeight);
    g2d.fillRect(playerX - playerWidth / 2, playerY, playerWidth / 2,
            playerHeight);
    // Right arm
    g2d.drawRect(playerX + playerWidth, playerY, playerWidth / 2,
            playerHeight);
    g2d.fillRect(playerX + playerWidth, playerY, playerWidth / 2,
            playerHeight);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillRect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the point where the player is located and the point where the bullet should go, you can define a line that goes through them. This will give you an equation like f(x) = a*x + b, which then you can use to calculate your coordinates for the path.

Check also the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29).